# Transform XML basing on XSLT in Ruby/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, nokogiri

I am trying to transform XML basing on XSLT in Ruby/Nokogiri.

```
doc   = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('some_file.xml'))
xslt  = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read('some_transformer.xslt'))

puts xslt.transform(doc)
```

but it fails:

> I/O warning : failed to load external entity "dateDifference.xsl"
>
> RuntimeError: compilation error: element stylesheet
>
> xsl:exclude-result-prefixes : undefined namespace exsl compilation
>
> error: element import xsl:import : unable to load dateDifference.xsl

probably, it is caused by using of external entities on my some_transform.xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:res="rate.fidelio.6.0" xmlns:inv="rtav.fidelio.4.0" xmlns:aravr="ravr.fidelio.2.0" xmlns:aravl="ravl.fidelio.2.0"  xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" exclude-result-prefixes="res inv aravr aravl date exsl">    
 <xsl:import href="dateDifference.xsl" />
 ...
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
> xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
> xmlns:res="rate.fidelio.6.0" 
> xmlns:inv="rtav.fidelio.4.0" 
> xmlns:aravr="ravr.fidelio.2.0" 
> xmlns:aravl="ravl.fidelio.2.0"  
> xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" 
> xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" 
> exclude-result-prefixes="res inv aravr aravl date exsl">
> ```

The error is exactly as per the error message:

The XSLT processor complains that there is no `"exsl"` namespace prefix declared, but it is listed in the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute.

**Correct this in the following way**:

```
exclude-result-prefixes="res inv aravr aravl date exslt"
```

**For the second problem**:

> error: element import xsl:import : unable to load dateDifference.xsl

This message means that there is no file named `dateDifference.xsl` in the same directory where the current XSLT file resides (or that the file is there but it is syntactically invalid, or that permissions are required to access the file, ... or, ...)

Comment: That solve "xsl:exclude-result-prefixes : undefined namespace exsl compilation" problem, but there is still problem with "error: element import xsl:import : unable to load dateDifference.xsl"

Comment: @Sergey, I updated this answer and explained the most likely causes for the second problem.